# How do I replace strings of a table from another table column

Tags: sql-server

How do I update/replace the value of the first table from the list of my second table in SQL. Sorry im not so good in using **replace()** of SQL especially replacing from values base from different table

First table.

```
ID | Value
======================
 1 | Fruits[Apple]
 2 | Fruits[Apple,Mango]
 3 | Apple[Red,Green]
```

Second table

```
Search | Replace
=========================
Apple  | Orange
Green  | Yellow
```

Comment: Typically I would use replace(). In your example do you want all instances of the word apple replaced? If you did both substitutions Row 3 would end up being: Orange[Red, Yellow]

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle SQL it goes like this :

```
UPDATE FIRST_TABLE FT
   SET FT.VALUE =
       (SELECT ST.REPLACE FROM SECOND_TABLE ST WHERE FT.VALUE = ST.SEARCH)
```

But for this this to work properly, keep in mind that the attribute `Search` in the `SECOND_TABLE` must be unique, otherswise you'll need to rearange your query.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT REPLACE(value,'apple','orange') from table1

Or to update:

Update table1 
set value = REPLACE(value, 'apple', 'orange')

If you have multiple substitutions you could use a cursor and variables.